# Referencing a Vue component (from a socket function)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

so what I am currently working on is using vue with socketIO. So I want a component that updates its data when the websocket emits something.
I looked at the following tutorial: https://medium.com/@michaelmangial1/getting-started-with-vue-js-socket-io-8d385ffb9782.

The connection to the websocket works fine however I don't know how I can change a data variable of the component or call a method of the component from the websocket function as I get the error that e.g. this.getAllLayouts is not a function. 
In the tutorial they just set `app.title = data.title;` in socket.on() as the Vue instance can be addresses as app.
But now I am confused. I wanted to use this in an component which I defined as a **single-file component**. So I can't use this app reference. But how can I reference the component in that case?

Below you can see the most important parts of this component. I defined the socket connection in the created() of the component

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import FirstPage from './FirstPage.vue';
import DNDAssign from './DNDAssign.vue';

export default {
  name: 'ControlCenter',
  data() {
    return {
      devices: [{ ip: 'yet unknown' }], // placeholder so line 12 does not throw error before actual device info fetched
      thisDeviceIndex: 0,
      currentLayoutIndex: 0,
      layouts: [],
    };
  },
  components: {
    DNDAssign,
    FirstPage,
  },
  methods: {
    getAllLayouts() {
      const path = 'http://192.168.0.38:5000/layouts';
      axios.get(path)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.layouts = response.data.layouts;
          this.devices = response.data.devices;
          this.thisDeviceIndex = response.data.your_device_index;
          console.log(this.layouts);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    // inital fetching of layouts
    console.log('fetching layouts from backend');
    this.getAllLayouts();

    // test websocket connection
    const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.38:5000');

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.error('connected to webSocket');
      socket.emit('my event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' });
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    socket.on('my response', function(data){
      console.log('got response');
      console.log(data.data);
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    socket.on('update_on_layouts', function(data){
      this.getAllLayouts(); //this does not work? How can I make it work or do something like
      // this.layouts = data;

    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that `this` inside that `fn` is not binded to `Vue`, you need to lexically bind it

Use `arrow method` to bind `this` to method

```js
socket.on('update_on_layouts', data => {
      this.getAllLayouts(); //this does not work? How can I make it work or do something like
      // this.layouts = data;

    });
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you a lot Satyam Pathak ^^  It is working as expected with your suggestion